# Change element ID using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<div id="content">
  Content
</div>
```

How would I change the ID of this div using Javascript?

Comment: could you please make the question clearer?

Comment: what div id? what do you mean you're having trouble changing it? you can't just change it in the markup?

Comment: Do not understand why this question was downvoted and penalized... was simple and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @paulywill Same, here!

Comment: @MichaelCoker He should have probably said: «Parametrically change element ...» or something along that line.

Answer (score 11):

Found this on the first result on a Google search:

```
document.getElementById("originalDivId").setAttribute("id", "newDivId");
```

`getElementById` does exactly what it says, it obtains the information of an element with the Id specified. `setAttribute` changes a HTML element's *attribute*, that is the stuff inside of the HTML tags (e.g. `class=""`, `id=""`, `style=""`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace a `<div>` element's ID with **[.setAttribute("id", "newID")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)**. This replaces the ID attribute of the target element with the value specified in the second parameter.

Here's an example showcasing this, changing the ID `original` to `modified`, and logging the change to the console:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("original").id);
document.getElementById("original").setAttribute("id", "modified");
console.log(document.getElementById("modified").id); // The same element
```

```html
<div id="original">
  Content
</div>
```

Note that you have to re-target with `document.getElementById("modified")` once the change has been applied.

Hope this helps! :)